# Very strange answer from server in socket communication

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi, telnet

I'm using a very simple code to connect to a telnet server (installed on a Raspberry Pi, and tested, it works). The code written for nodejs, tries to work as a telnet client, but at he time of connection the data I get is not something that I could understand.

Code:

```
var net = require('net');

var socket = net.createConnection(23, 'addressorip.rpi.com');
console.log('Socket created.');
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  // Log the response from the HTTP server.
  console.log('RESPONSE: ' + data);
}).on('connect', function() {
  console.log('connected');
  //socket.write();
}).on('end', function() {
  console.log('DONE');
});
```

Output on shell:

> C:\Documents and Settings\testdir>node telnet_test.js
>
> Socket created.
>
> connected
>
> RESPONSE: ??↑?? ??#??'

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll answer my own question since I discoverd what happened.

When I tried to connect to the Telnet server using nodeJs sockets, I thought I was going to get a string requesting the username. However, as I always connected directly to telehack.com's telnet server and I couldn't understand what was going on. Well, the answer is here:

[Source](http://mud-dev.wikidot.com/telnet:negotiation#toc1)

> It is not required that you implementing telnet negotiation in any clients and servers you may create, but you need to be aware of it in order to avoid problems that its presence on the other end of your connection may otherwise cause. As a byte-based protocol, a value of 255 (named IAC) is reserved to indicate that a negotiation sequence follows. In order to actually send a value of 255, you need to be escape it. You can do this by sending it twice in a row.

Then I understood that the server was trying to negotiate. So was actually getting this:

[image: wireshark]

Then the solution to this problem is to implement the negotiation protocol to deal with this TELNET commands sent from the server.